# Heroku Access to my local windows directory

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to develop a web app using python and flask. The idea is to read a file from my local directory, modify the data and store it in a different file(Ack.txt) in another directory. This is running fine in my localhost.

When i deploy the same on Heroku, i am not able to see the generated file in my local filesystem.

Is there any way to achieve this without using AWS s3 or something similar.

Basically achieve the same functionality in Heroku:

```
op_file = open(r'D:\blblba\output\Ack.txt', 'a+')
    if op_file.mode == 'a+':
        op_file.write(final_content)
    op_file.close()
```

Comment: "The idea is to read a file from my local directory, modify the data and store it in a different file(Ack.txt) in another directory."—This will never work. How do you expect Heroku to access your local filesystem? Imagine the security risks if arbitrary web applications could reach into your personal files and modify them.

Comment: (The reason it works on your local machine is that your local machine is also your development server. Back-end code can modify files on the _server_, but not on the _client_.)

Comment: `i am not able to see the generated file in my local filesystem.` Just to be clear, are you hoping to see changes in the remote deployment reflected on your machine?